# Passing string/path arguments on my main program to open image files

Tags: java, swing, arguments, file-association

I'm trying to make a program similar to Windows Photo Viewer, the program that pops up usually if you double-click an image in Windows. I've already made my own program, however it uses a `JFileChooser` associated with a button to bring up images to open inside the application itself (Windows photo app doesn't seem to do this).

Question:

How can I make my application handle certain file types when its double-clicked from Windows? My guess would be something along the lines of my main class having a Path/String type argument of the file I want to open, but I'm not sure how to exactly implement that.

What type does Windows pass to a program whenever we open a file? String?

Once my first question is fixed, is there anything special I would need to do to associate my program to image files (when making .exe file or installer)?

Comment: Have you tried a [tag:java-web-start] `<association/>`, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12323471/230513)?

Comment: @trashgod: I don't think file associations is my priority atm. I need to be able to take String arguments for my program first. I did check on that already however. It seems I need to be online to run the application (correct me if I'm wrong). I want my program to be able to run just like Windows Photo Viewer, which is just a default offline application integrated to Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Include a [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start) [`<association/>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html) tag as a "hint to the JNLP client that it wishes to be registered with the operating system as the primary handler of certain extensions and a certain mime-type." Note that " the `<offline-allowed/>` element must also be included." A web server is *not* required and a platform-specific `<shortcut/>` is optional. The file to open will be a command line parameter.